# IPSec tunnel on ASA keeps disconnecting

Tags: cisco-asa, ipsec, microsoft-ftmg-2010

I have an ASA IPSec tunnel configured between an ASA5505 and Microsoft TMG 2010 SP2.

The tunnel sometimes works for a few hours, and then disconnects, and other times it works for 5 minutes and then disconnects.

When it disconnects, it sometimes takes 10 minutes to re-establish the SA, sometimes takes 45 minutes to re-establish the SA.

I have a suspicion one side of the tunnel is re-keying the connection and the other isn't, but I don't really know how to troubleshoot this. Troubleshooting from the ASA end is substantially easier than troubleshooting from the TMG end due to the obtuse nature of getting this information out of TMG; although I suspect that the TMG is where the problem lies.

Where can I go in the ASA to determine why the IPSec tunnels are dropping?

Comment: Is there constant traffic through the tunnel, or is it intermittent?

Comment: debug crypto ipsec and isakmp on ASA?

Comment: @ShaneMadden - traffic should be reasonably constant. Not heavy, but a sustained traffic of maybe 128kbps or so

Comment: @xeon - dumb question (I'm pretty much an ASA noob): I have run those two commands; now what?

Comment: logging enable, logging console 7, terminal monitor should give you messages to console.  I dont have an ASA in front of me to confirm commands and depends on your ASA OS version.  You will get a lot of information, if you are using putty or something extend how many lines before it clears.

Comment: Interesting. The ASA is saying that the tunnels are still up, but there is no traffic flowing over them. I think I might have a different question that I will ask separately if I can't figure it out.

Comment: Are you sure your subnets and other information matches on each end?

Comment: Also check your routes

Comment: @KeithStokes - 99% sure. I have deleted the config from both ends and re-created it multiple times. I'm new to IPSec tunnels on ASA's rather than flooding the community with noob questions I'll soldier on and see what I can find with this new info.

Comment: Or I will succumb and open a case with TAC...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though both sides of the tunnel had volume-based rekeying disabled, one of the sides was attempting to re-key anyway (I'm not sure which; I suspect the TMG). So after weeks of troubleshooting, I set a rekey after 4GB on both sides of the link and it has been rock solid ever since.

The time-based rekey is 1 hour; and it's highly unlikely that 4GB of traffic will flow over that link in an hour, so it's been stable ever since.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any routing protocols through the tunnel?  If so, double check that you aren't getting a route to the remote endpoint address through the tunnel.  e.g. If you have a tunnel between 1.2.3.4 and 2.3.4.5, make sure that you have a static route on 1.2.3.4 to 2.3.4.5 that goes via the appropriate next hop address.

The symptoms you are seeing are similar to what I've seen when I've made this error, because the tunnel goes up and down constantly.  First it establishes the tunnel, then it establishes the routing neighbourship, then it exchanges routes, and often the remote endpoint's connected routes are sent through.  So then the route to the remote endpoint is through the tunnel, which times out, and then the neighbourship fails, which means the routes are removed, and the tunnel can come up again.  This cycle repeats endlessly until you add the appropriate static route.